# Code in Spoiler broken (again?)

Tags: bug, status-completed, formatting, spoilers

This one looks pretty funny actually:

[image]

Found [in this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40747/8478).

This is in Chrome 38 on Windows 8.

Comment: Spoilers work with `<code>` tags or backticks, but apparently not `<pre>` tags.

Comment: It hides the code, doesn't it? ;-)

Comment: No-repro in latest Chrome with SOUP installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added a `pre` rule to the CSS.

With you in the next build.

Answer (score 5):

It is caused by this CSS rule:

```
.spoiler {
    color: #FFF9E3;
}
```

All text is colored in the same color as the spoiler background, and so is the text in the code block.

A potential solution could be:

```
.spoiler pre {
    background: #FFF9E3;
}
```